# What is the right way to load different js file for each template in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to load different `.js`, `.css` files (**static files**) for each template, but also to load same group of files for each of them.

**Example:**

`first.html` - Here I want to load `jquery.js`, `jquery.css`, `maps.js`

`second.html` - Here I want to load `jquery.js`, `jquery.css` **without** `maps.js`

`third.html` - Here I want to load `test.js`, `maps.js`

Right now I add all files in `footer.html` (`.js` files), or `header.html` (`.css` files) and include all of them, via `{% include 'footer.html' %}`

Comment: Use [blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). If all your html files `{% extend %}` a file `base.html` then put the common files in base.html, then an empty block `{% block page_scripts %}` in base.html that you fill with the specific scripts in each page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files should all extend a *base.html* file:

```
{% extend base.html %}
```

Then in *base.html*, add all the common scripts and css. Those will be inherited by all the templates. Also add an empty block `page_scripts` that you then fill in your various templates:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'jquery.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  <footer>
    <script src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}"></script>
    {% block page_scripts %}{# Specific template scripts here #}{% endblock %}
  </footer>
</body>
```

Finally in your child templates, e.g. *first.html*:

```
{% block page_scripts %}
  <script src="{% static 'maps.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

In this example, *jquery.css* and *jquery.js* are common for all templates. And *maps.js* is only loaded in your *first.html* page.